# preg_match_all find text between two words, print

Tags: php, preg-match-all

i want to get all html classes that are vip, and print each vip result

```
$text = "<enty> hello baby, we love osama:) That means 2016 set a global heat record<enty2016>for the third year in a row</enty2016>according to NOAA and NASA, who held a joint press conference on Wednesday to discuss the record. <endentry> <enty2016>Temperatures over the Earth's continents and oceans in 2016 were 1.1 degree Celsius (1.98 degrees Fahrenheit) </enty2016>above the pre-industrial average, according to the WMO. That means we are already a <endline>majority of the way to the 1.5-degree warming goal <endenty> ";
```

i want to print all data in enty2016s

```
preg_match("/<enty2016>(.*?)<\/enty2016>/is", $html, $matches); 
foreach($matches[1] as $enty2016s){
echo $enty2016s;
}
```

Comment: use the DOM, not a regex.

Comment: somtimes i am not searching html

Comment: your example is html, if you have other examples, you should post them.

Comment: well i tried domdodcument it crashes the entire page  $html = new simple_html_dom();   
$html->load($html); 
$items = $html->find('div.vip',0)->children(1)->outertext; 
print_r($items);

Answer (score 1):

I will use `DOMDocument` in combination with `DOMXPath`:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
$divNodeList = $xp->query('//div[@class="vip"]/text()');

foreach ($divNodeList as $divNode) {
    echo $divNode->nodeValue . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: what if class name has line break in it?  data-vip-url="/v.index"
        class="
            search-item
             regular-ad

Comment: www.kijiji.ca/b-cars-vehicles/british-columbia/ford-carproof/k0c27l9007

Comment: html class names don't have line breaks nor any whitespaces. A class attribute that contains several classnames can have whitespaces, in this case change the xpath query predicate using the `contains` function.

Comment: in the url i provded the class name has line breaks

Comment: One more time, a class name can't have whitespace characters, in your example the class attribute contains two different class names: `search-item` and `regular-ad`. As I said previously, if you want to target this kind of class attributes, use the `contains` function in the xpath query (read an xpath tutorial).

Comment: @newuser0250 It appears that you have upvoted everything that Casimir has posted, but there is no green tick.  Please work toward resolution by either awarding the green tick or explaining what isn't working properly.